# RedirectMatch overrides Redirect in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

In my `.htaccess` file I have rules for redirection.

```
Redirect 301 /abc/ newdomain.example/abc-new/ 

Redirect 301 /def/ newdomain.example/def-new/

Redirect 301 /ghi/ newdomain.example/ghi-new/

RedirectMatch 301 ^/ newdomain.example
```

My expectations are:

1. when somebody types `olddomain.example/abc` is redirected to `newdomain.example/abc-new/`, `olddomain.example/def` is redirected to `newdomain.example/def-new/`.
2. when somebody types for example `olddomain.example/xyz` is redirected to `newdomain.example`

In example above all pages like `olddomain.example/abc`  `olddomain.example/def`  are redirected to `newdomain.example`

When line with RedirectMatch is removed redirctions works.

I was expecting that according to documentation rules in file are analyzed from top to bottom and when something matches it is picked up. Here it looks like RedirectMatch overrides the rules above.

Comment: You are using `olddomain.example/abc` in your examples twice with conflicting expectations.  I expect that you want something that isn't `abc`, `def` or `ghi` to redirect using the last rule.

Comment: You are right, I fixed my post, my point is when somebody types something different than defined in rules for example olddomain.example/xyz should be redirected to newdomain.example

Comment: Shouldn't `olddomain.example/xyz` get redirected to `newdomain.example/xyz`?  It is bad for usability and SEO to redirect everything to the home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `RedirectMatch` in this case.  `Redirect` rules are all "starts with" rules.  So you can simplify that to:

```bash
Redirect 301 /abc https://newdomain.example/abc-new 
Redirect 301 /def https://newdomain.example/def-new
Redirect 301 /ghi https://newdomain.example/ghi-new
Redirect 301 / https://newdomain.example/
```

I tested this on my local server:

```bash
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example/foo| grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example | grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example/ | grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example/abc | grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/abc-new
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example/abc/ | grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/abc-new/
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example/abc/path | grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/abc-new/path
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example/xyz | grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/xyz
```

If you really want to redirect everything else to the home page (not recommended), you can use the following:

```bash
Redirect 301 /abc https://newdomain.example/abc-new 
Redirect 301 /def https://newdomain.example/def-new
Redirect 301 /ghi https://newdomain.example/ghi-new
RedirectMatch 301 /.* https://newdomain.example/
```

Also tested on my local server:

```bash
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example | grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example/ | grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example/abc | grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/abc-new
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example/abc/ | grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/abc-new/
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example/abc/path | grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/abc-new/path
$ curl -s --head https://olddomain.example/xyz | grep Location
Location: https://newdomain.example/
```